# Android App Bundle build error: File 'root/lib/x86/ffmpeg' uses directory name 'lib'

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, android-app-bundle

I have used FFmpeg Android in the project from this repo [FFmpeg-Android-Java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) and implement only the **FFmpegAndroid** module in the project.

FFmpeg library is working fine when we run directly from Android Studio or we make APK file (debug or Signed).

But When I try to generate the app bundle from Android studio I get the below error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  > File 'root/lib/x86/ffmpeg' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.
```

> Project Level **build.gradle**

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

// Different version declaration
ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.4.0'
    supportVersion = "28.0.0"
    retrofitVersion = "2.0.2"
    okhttp3Version = "3.2.0"
    smackVersion = "4.3.0"
    nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    classpath "com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0"
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
}
}

 allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
         mavenCentral()
     }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you file a bug with Android Grade plugin with how you included this dependency in your build.gradle?

Comment: @Pierre, I have added images which shows how it implemented as a module.

Comment: @Pierre, Everything is working fine when I run the app or create apk and install. I didn't face any Gradle issue.

Comment: What version of AGP do you use?

Comment: @Pierre, I used '4.0.1' for the Android Gradle plugin.

Comment: Can you file a bug here please? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192709&template=842921

Comment: @Pierre, I am not able to create an issue and getting an error message as "You do not have permission to create issues in this component."

Comment: My bad, it should be https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533 Details provided at https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs

Comment: @Pierre created an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167976852